# Placing code in between conditions of an 'if' statement

Tags: c++, linked-list, logic

I currently have an if statement, executing from within a function, that looks like this, but which doesn't compile, although I know it's because of the code I'm executing in between conditions 2 and 3.

What I'm trying to do is create a function that will inserted a new node into a sorted linked list of integers at the correct position. Do do this, I need to test for three conditions. The first is whether or not the list is empty. If it is then `condition1` is satisfied and all is good. The second condition is whether or not there is only a single node currently in the list. If this is the case, then `condition2` is satisfied and again all is good.

Now we come to the problem. If the first two conditions are not satisfied, then the only other possibility is that the list contains at least two nodes. In this case, the two temporary pointers need to be initialised, one pointing to `Head` and one to `Head -> Next` in order to keep track of the current position in the list and facilitate the insertion of the new node into the list.

These are initialised using the code the is placed between `condition2` and `condition3`. These have to be created because `condition3` relies on them, but creating them before the `condition1` would result in a segmentation fault.

Can anyone advise me on how to go about implementing such a statement, or if it's even possible? I want to keep the code as simple as possible, and the fully functioning `LinkedList :: Insert()` function I have right now is a mess of `if` statements and I'm having trouble following some of the code.

```
int NewElement;
Node *NewNode;
NewNode = new Node;
NewNode -> Element = NewElement;

Node *TempPrevious;
Node *TempNext;

    if (ListIsEmpty) // condition1
    {
        // some code
        return true;
    }

    else if (ListContainsOnlyOneNode) // condition2
    {
         // some code
         return false;
    }

    TempPrevious = Head;
    TempNext = Head -> Next;

    else if (NewNode -> Element > TempNext -> Element) // condition3
    {
          // some code
          return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is... actually really easy. Because you're `return`ing from each block, you don't need `else` at all!

```
if (ListIsEmpty) // condition1
{
    // some code
    return true;
}

// you don't have anything that needs to happen here, but you *could*
// since if condition1 is met control leaves the function immediately

if (ListContainsOnlyOneNode) // condition2
{
     // some code
     return false;
}

// if either of the previous conditions are met, 
// control will never reach this point! So put whatever setup you need for 
// the final test here

TempPrevious = Head;
TempNext = Head -> Next;

if (NewNode -> Element > TempNext -> Element) // condition3
{
      // some code
      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the last `else` and I think it will work as you like.